# UIScrollView automatic content inset behavior working in iOS 11 but not iOS 10?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, ios10, uiedgeinsets

I'm new to the game so I've really only worked with `iOS 11` and have recently acquired heartburn trying to figure out what Apple had in mind with their now-deprecated inset behaviors in `iOS 10`. And Apple's documentation for `UIScrollView` inset adjustment behavior is almost exclusively for `iOS 11`.

Programmatic setup:

```
func setView() {

    view = UIView()
    view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

func addScrollView() {

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    }
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

}

func addFirstView() {

    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(firstView)
    firstView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    firstView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

}

...

func addLastView() {

    lastView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.addSubview(lastView)
    lastView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    lastView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    lastView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    lastView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    lastView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

This setup works perfectly in `iOS 11` (content insets are automatically adjusted) but in `iOS 10` the content inset is not adjusted--the first view is flush with the view's top anchor (not the bottom of the status bar as it should be). `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is `true` by default. How do I enable automatic content inset adjustment behavior in `iOS 10`?

Comment: did you try `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` ?

Comment: But I want them enabled.